# Windows refuses to add an additional DC

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, domain-controller

I am trying to add a second DC to my network. It seems to go well: I install AD DS on a second server, I enter my credentials and the domain, and the domain is shown. I choose it, but when I click 'Next' it says a DC for this domain can't be found.

I am not sure what is causing this error and if it's a common problem (what I do know, is that it's very annoying...)

Comment: Is your actual DC works also as a DNS server for your domain ? If yes, is the server you are trying to promote is configured to point to your actual DC in its DNS settings ?

Comment: @krisFR: the primary DC is not a DNS server, the domain points to my DC though; after all, I can see all the domains in the forest when connecting.

Comment: Screenshots?  Step by step description of what you are doing?  ipconfig for the server you are trying to join?  In fact any information beyond 'I can see all the domains' and 'DNS is set up correctly' would be helpful.  WRT DNS, we'll be the judge of whether it's set up correctly.  If everything was set up correctly then you wouldn't be here, eh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was indeed related to DNS. I was 100% sure it wasn't (as I confirmed it before), apparently it was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you mean when you say that you `see all the domains in the forest`, but you need to configure the DNS client settings on the server you're trying to promote to use a DNS server that hosts your AD DNS zone. The server you're trying to promote needs to locate a domain controller for the domain in question, and it does so by querying the DNS server holding the AD DNS zone.

Comment: What I mean with `see all the domains in the forest`, when I enter my credentials, a popup appears showing all domains in the forest.